# Psmouse serio2: Failed to disable mouse on synaptics-pt/serio0

Tags: linux-mint, mouse, hid

I am currently using Linux Mint 21.1 Cinnamon and I keep getting the error:

```
psmouse serio2: failed to disable mouse on synaptics-pt/serio0
```

I only ever get it after shutting down my computer if I've connected to my home internet and used my browser (Firefox) while it was on.

After researching into it, I've found that a lot of people have gotten a similar error that brings up

```
psmouse serio1: failed to disable mouse on isa0060/serio1
```

in their log, with it apparently being just a bug. I was wondering if the error I was getting was any different. I can't find anything online about it when I search it up.

Also, what's `serio0`? I have messages that start with `psmouse serio1` and `psmouse serio2` but not for `psmouse serio0`.